# operator< for user defined key of map - C2679

Tags: visual-c++, operator-keyword, stdmap

I'm trying to create a map like

```
std::map<std::map <std::string,std::string>, MyDataTyp*>,
```

therefore I put

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>
```

in a separate class like:

```
class TagList {
public:
std::map<std::string, std::string> _map;

TagList() {}
~TagList() {}
void addTag(const std::string tag, const std::string value) { if (tag != "") _map[tag] = value; }
std::string getValue(const std::string tag) {
    std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it = _map.find(tag);
    if (it == _map.end()) return ("");
    else return (it->second);
}

};

inline bool operator< (const TagList &a, const TagList &b) {

std::map<std::string, std::string>::iterator it ;
for (it = a._map.begin(); it != a._map.end(); it++) {
    std::string myVal1 = it->second;
    std::string myVal2 = b._map.find(it->first);
    if (myVal2 == "") return false;
    if (strcmp(myVal1.c_str(),myVal2.c_str()) > 0) return true;

}
return false;
```

}

Hope someone can explain me the error message

> Error  4   error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)    (...)

...and what is the reason for my confision....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my fault...

found the answer by myself:

```
inline bool operator< (const TagList &a, const TagList &b) {

std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it ;
std::map<std::string, std::string>::const_iterator it2 ;
for (it = a._map.begin(); it != a._map.end(); it++) {
    std::string myVal1 = it->second;
    it2 = b._map.find(it->first);
    std::string myVal2 = it2->second;
    if (myVal2 == "") return false;
    if (strcmp(myVal1.c_str(),myVal2.c_str()) > 0) return true;

}
return false;
}
```

it wasn't const

Thx
George